# Solve equations and inequations in undetermined linear equations?

Tags: inequality

All the linear equations  can't be solved or be proved not to be solved. But if the linear equation contains some restricttion, how to prove it can't be solve or how to get linear solution? For example

\begin{align}
a+b+c+d+e&=10\\
c+d&=12\\
a&>9\\
b&<6\\
\end{align}

How should I get the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would proceed to solve the system as usual and then apply the restriction.  In your particular example, we have $d = 12-c$ and $e=-a-b-2$, so a general solution would be:
\begin{align*}(a,b,c,d,e) &= (a,b,c,12-c,10-a-b-c-(12-c)) \\
&= (a,b,c,12-c,-2-a-b),
\end{align*}
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\cap S$, where $S$ is our restriction set.  In this case, we require that $a \ge 10 > 9$ and $b \le 5 < 6$, so our solution set will be as above, except $a$ has to be at least $10$ and $b$ has to be no more than $5$.  One such solution would be $(10, 5, 0, 12, 10)$.

Comment: But Mathematica give this result: `a > 9 && b == -2 - a - I Im[e] - Re[e] && c < 6 && 
 d == 10 - a - b - c - e` How can I get this result?

Comment: Well, assuming $e$ is real, that is precisely equivalent to what I wrote, since $\text{Im}(e) = 0$.  Remember, you have more variables than equations, which implies there will be degrees of freedom.  There are multiple ways to write the same set of solutions.

Comment: It doesn't even make sense for this problem to be in the complex numbers, because if $a \in \mathbb{C}$, then $a > 9$ doesn't mean anything.

Comment: But in your answer, can't fiind $c<6$

Comment: @Y.zeng You didn't write anything about $c < 6$, only $b < 6$.

Comment: Yes. You are right!